# how to get Office outlook 2010 working with adobe acrobat 9

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, adobe-acrobat

How do i get outlook 2010 working with adobe acrobat 9.
The feature I am looking for is to convert my mail as pdf and
 
the  attachments.
[image: adobe-pdf-ribbon]

the screen-shot i think is taken with adobe acrobat 10.
i am in a business so upgrading to the latest right away is not an option!

edit:
I know of tools like FreePDF, And they work great for mail or multiple mails.
 
But not for the attachments. If it's possible i would like that the attached jpg/png/doc/doc etc... etc... etc... could be put in the pdf file?

Comment: Is that function/feature available in Acrobat v9.x?

Comment: I have zero issues using Adobe Acrobat 9 with Office 2010.  I was able to export mail within Exchange into a PDF file without a problem.

Comment: In that case, perhaps the IT Department have not deployed the Outlook integration?

Comment: @mitch yes that features is available(called PDFMaker). Worked with outlook 2007 and was available for outlook 2010. but was disable for 2010 because it made it crash? some how see http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/known-issues-acrobat-9-pdfmaker.html#main_Outlook_2010_quits_when_PDFMaker_is_installed

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be a "Print to PDF" capability. CutePDF or NitroPDF Reader both have the capability to do this for example and are commonly licensed by businesses to allow easy conversion to PDF from any file format.

Comment: I know this to be possible considering I am looking at the option to convert "selected messages" on the `Adobe PDF` tab.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I thought from the question that you had seen this somewhere else using 10 but that you are using 9. I've changed my answer.